# How to implement elasticsearch with autocompelete in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

Hi guys i want to implement elastic search in my rails app with auto complete i am able to implement that, but my problem is when we click on any suggestion than how can i get the id of that record to find only that particular record. please tell me as soon as possible. and please tell me best way to implement elastic search in rails app

Comment: You could try this gem https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails.

Comment: bro i am using the same but please tell me about autocomplete issue, how i will get id of selected data?